# Example Maven pom.xml for Java based Selenium WebDriver project for Firefox

Tags: java, maven, firefox, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I would like to automate `Firefox` using `Java` through a `Selenium WebDriver` project.

As I never used `Selenium` nor `Maven` before I'm not familiar with how to set up a suitable `Maven pom.xml` file to create a project, which then can be imported into Eclipse.

On http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-webdriver I found the following example for the opera browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MySel20Proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySel20Proj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.28.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Would you be so kind and show me how to adapt this `pom.xml` to apply for the Firefox browser, say `Firefox 17`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With selenium-java dependency you get all java bindings for all browsers.  So, you do not need to change anything in your pom from what you already have.  The only thing that would change is your driver initialization code, which is driver = new FirefoxDriver() instead of OperaDriver.

Comment: Thanks! I misinterpreted the opera dependency in the pom.xml file and thought a corresponding Firefox section would be required.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic POM taken from https://github.com/Ardesco/selenium-standalone-server-plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-template</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<name>Selenium Maven Template</name>
<description>A Maven Template For Selenium</description>
<url>http://www.lazerycode.com</url>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache 2</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
    </license>
</licenses>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <selenium.version>2.45.0</selenium.version>
    <overwrite.binaries>false</overwrite.binaries>
    <browser>firefox</browser>
    <threads>1</threads>
    <remote>false</remote>
    <seleniumGridURL/>
    <platform/>
    <browserVersion/>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>selenium-tests</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>${standalone.binary.root.folder}</rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                        <downloadedZipFileDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/selenium_standalone_zips</downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                        <customRepositoryMap>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/RepositoryMap.xml</customRepositoryMap>
                        <overwriteFilesThatExist>${overwrite.binaries}</overwriteFilesThatExist>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>selenium</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <parallel>methods</parallel>
                        <threadCount>${threads}</threadCount>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <browser>${browser}</browser>
                            <screenshotDirectory>${project.build.directory}/screenshots</screenshotDirectory>
                            <remoteDriver>${remote}</remoteDriver>
                            <gridURL>${seleniumGridURL}</gridURL>
                            <desiredPlatform>${platform}</desiredPlatform>
                            <desiredBrowserVersion>${browserVersion}</desiredBrowserVersion>

                            <!--Set properties passed in by the driver binary downloader-->
                            <phantomjs.binary.path>${phantomjs.binary.path}</phantomjs.binary.path>
                            <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                            <webdriver.ie.driver>${webdriver.ie.driver}</webdriver.ie.driver>
                            <webdriver.opera.driver>${webdriver.opera.driver}</webdriver.opera.driver>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*WebDriver.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This will:

- Download all required Selenium libraries
- Download the standalone driver binaries (e.g. chromedriver, phantomJS, etc)
- Download the PhantomJSdriver libraries
- Add TestNG as a test framework
- Add in all the Hamcrest matchers for clear test assertions (see https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial)

The original link will take you to a basic project setup that you can just check out and run if you want more than just a POM.

Comment: IDEA reports an error _Cannot resolve symbol 'webdriver.chrome.driver'_ . How to fix this?

Comment: Run a maven lifecycle (e.g. verify) through IDEA.  If you are not running a Maven process Maven will not be able to specify the driver location.  If you want to run a test through IDEA without invoking maven you will need to set the value of 'webdriver.chrome.driver' as part of the test configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I know, that Firefox 17 was not supported in 2.28.0, but browsing the [Selenium project homepage](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/) gave me new insight - latest release is `2.30.0` so update this:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

To this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.30.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Clean, and try again. Hopefully it helps. The general advice here is: Always use the latest version of Selenium

Comment: 2.28 does support FF 17 since FF17 support was added in 2.27 itself as per http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG

Comment: No problem :) I know that some had no issues ;) But the solution was different ;)

Comment: Today I tried the same example from the documentation, and it wasn't working in Firefox 32. After changing the dependency version from `2.42.2` to `2.43.1` the example ran. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To use only the FirefoxDriver implementation, you don't have to use the selenium-java artifact. Rather, you can just add the dependency on the Firefox artifact. Add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.practicemaven</groupId>
<artifactId>com.practicemaven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>com.practicemaven</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <browser>chrome</browser>
                    <env>amazonqaurl</env>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/amazontest.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>

</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).